# MySQL Profiling

Tags: mysql, profiler

Our application uses a MySql database. I want to view the query that is getting executed on a user action in the application.

SQL Profiling is the first thing came to my mind and I followed [this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20110609054749/http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html). I am getting the query profiles that are executed in that particular session where i `set profiling = 1;` . How can i view the queries that are getting executed in my application?

Comment: In my opinion, "Profiling" is usually useless.  That article is nearly a decade old.  It was deprecated in 5.6.7, four years ago.  The performance_schema is replacing it.  I'll second Károly's comments about the general and slow logs.  If you have performance issues, then use the slowlog and `pt-query-digest`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options to do so.

1# Probably the easiest is to turn on general query logging:

```
set global general_log=ON;
set global general_log_file='/tmp/query.log';
```

Then you can see all the queries being executed in the file.

2# Another option is to use slow logs with `long_query_time=0`. This you can manage on session level:

```
set long_query_time = 0;
```

Slow log also has a bit more information than general log.

3# You can use tcpdump and [percona-toolkit](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-query-digest.html) to retrieve the queries:

```
tcpdump -s 65535 -x -nn -q -tttt -i any -c 1000 port 3306 > mysql.tcp.txt

pt-query-digest --type tcpdump mysql.tcp.txt
```

4# Profiling also work

```
set profiling=1
show profiles;
+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| Query_ID | Duration   | Query                    |
+----------+------------+--------------------------+
...
|        3 | 0.01397050 | select * from mysql.user |
+----------+------------+--------------------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

show profile for query 3;
```

This has the biggest overhead and also in my opinion the most cumbersome.

Comment: Option 1 is super cool. Using it. Cheers.